# How to export CloudWatch Dashboard data to share with people with no AWS account.

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I set up monitoring and alarms about active connections to the loadbalancer, CPU and Memory usage from all of my instances with CloudWatch. And my client (the owner of the product in the website) wants me to share all these numbers and possibly graphs of those so he can see how the system is behaving, etc. He doesn't have an AWS account.

Is there any feature in CloudWatch that can give me these results, graphs or numbers?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [Reduce Time to Resolution with Amazon CloudWatch Snapshot Graphs and Alerts | AWS DevOps Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/reduce-time-to-resolution-with-amazon-cloudwatch-snapshot-graphs-and-alerts/):

> You can use snapshot graphs to integrate and display CloudWatch charts outside of the AWS
>   Management Console to improve monitoring visibility or reduce time to resolution. This feature
>   makes it possible for you to display CloudWatch charts on your webpage or integrate charts with
>   third-party tools, such as ticketing, chat applications, and bug tracking.

Also see part 2: [Building an Amazon CloudWatch Dashboard Outside of the AWS Management Console | AWS DevOps Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/building-an-amazon-cloudwatch-dashboard-outside-of-the-aws-management-console/)

Answer (score 3):

We use [Datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com/) for some of our devops analytics.  If you want something more hands on, you can setup [Grafana](https://grafana.com/), it has a plugin to pull data from CloudWatch.

Answer (score 2):

A new AWS feature was added that allows for the creation of a shareable link to any cloudwatch dashboard -- whether or not you are logged in to an AWS account or were granted permissions.  Hand the link to the 3rd party.

We have added them to our wiki pages.  Still trying to figure out how to render the dashboards in confluence pages, but the link itself works fine.

[CW dashboard sharing](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/09/amazon-cloudwatch-dashboards-supports-sharing/?sc_channel=em&sc_campaign=Launch_mult_OT_awsroadmapemail_20200910&sc_medium=em_whats_new&sc_content=launch_ot_ot&sc_country=mult&sc_geo=mult&sc_category=mult&sc_outcome=launch)

Comment: Please add explanation to the answer instead of just a link

Comment: Yes, that was a bit terse.  Have added more context

Comment: @VaTo, This should be the accepted answer as of now

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same problem, and came up with an API that you can use to create public versions (semi-public, using a pre-signed s3 url) for Cloudwatch dashboards.
Here's a link to the documentation [enter link description here](https://dhorions.github.io/publicclouddashboard/).
Disclaimer : this is not 100% free, for heavy use and frequently updated dashboards, there's a small price using a [rapidapi subscription](https://rapidapi.com/quodlibet/api/publiccloudwatchdashboard).